# New AMD 6700 GPU. Ubuntu doesn't recoginize monitor connected via DisplayPort. xRandar doesn't see the ports

Tags: multiple-monitors, amd-graphics, displayport

I bought a PowerColor Bc-2235 video card using a AMD 6700 (non-XT) GPU. The card works just fine with mi HDMI monitor, but I can't make it work with a secundary monitor connected via DisplayPort. The monitor is not picked up even if it is the only one connected, but I confirmed that it works fine by testing it in another PC and by connecting it to the HDMI port using and adaptator.

In addition to this, it seems that the port itself is not recognized. This is the output of xrandr with both monitors connected:

```
❯ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
HDMI-A-0 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 521mm x 293mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  71.91    50.00    59.94  
   1680x1050     59.88  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.90  
   1280x800      59.91  
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1024x768      70.07    60.00  
   800x600       72.19    60.32    56.25  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   640x480       72.81    66.67    60.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  

❯ xrandr --listproviders
Providers: number : 1
Provider 0: id: 0x55 cap: 0x9, Source Output, Sink Offload crtcs: 6 outputs: 1 associated providers: 0 name:Unknown AMD Radeon GPU @ pci:0000:09:00.0
```

I am using Ubuntu 23.04, but the same behavior is seen using a 22.04 liveUSB.

Any suggestion to what to try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Check if it works on Windows
2. Try [newer firmware versions](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/). Run `sudo make install` with the latest firmware files.
3. Try a newer [mainline kernel](https://kernel.ubuntu.com/%7Ekernel-ppa/mainline/) and see if the problem goes away.
4. Try a different DisplayPort cable.
5. Try the other DisplayPort ports.

If it works on Windows but it does not on Linux after doing both steps 2 & 3; fill in a report to [Mesa's DRM bugtracker](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/mesa/drm/-/issues/) with a detailed explanation of everything you tried (plugging one monitor to which ports, plugging two monitors to which ports) and the outputs of apps you're getting at each step.

If it does not work on Windows either then your GPU is defective and seek RMA.

Comment: I ended up installing Windows. It doesn't detect the monitor there either, so it is not a problem of linux.